# Running multiprocessing pool with a different executable in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is it possible to run a multiprocessing pool (or a subprocess) with a different executable than the main process in Python?

The use case I have in mind is running some one-off tests in parallel using different virtualenvs at the same time, for gathering some data for different library versions.

The issues I can forsee is that pickling/sharing things between subprocesses this way might not be trivial, as the library versions could be different. However, simple data types (lists, dicts) will probably work.

Comment: I think you might be better off using `tox` for testing with multiple virtualenvs? https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That's a good point, and I might have done that for integration or unit tests. What I had in mind was more along the lines of gathering data from different versions of the same library (so more like a one-off thing). I'll update the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`multiprocessing.spawn()` supports changing the interpreter, but not concurrently.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L24-L46)

If that's a problem, just a `subprocess` with `stdin` and `stdout` in binary mode and schlepping a pickle up and down the pipe (that sounded wrong) should do the trick... This assumes the parent is running Python 3.

```py
import sys
import pickle
import subprocess
import random
import io

# Grab hold of binary I/O streams

if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    i_stream = sys.stdin.buffer
    o_stream = sys.stdout.buffer
else:
    i_stream = sys.stdin
    o_stream = sys.stdout


def child():
    input_data = pickle.loads(i_stream.read())
    output_data = dict(
        input_data,
        random_twice=input_data["random"] * 2,
        version=tuple(sys.version_info),
    )
    o_stream.write(pickle.dumps(output_data, protocol=2))


def parent():
    # The highest protocol supported by Python 2.7 is version 2.
    input_data = pickle.dumps(
        {"hello": "world", "random": random.randint(1, 100000)},
        protocol=2,
    )
    for python in ("python2.7", "python3.7"):
        proc = subprocess.run(
            ["/usr/bin/env", python, sys.argv[0], "child"],
            check=True,
            encoding=None,
            input=input_data,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        print(python, pickle.loads(proc.stdout))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "child" in sys.argv:
        child()
    else:
        parent()
```

outputs

```
python2.7 {'random_twice': 174850, 'random': 87425, 'hello': 'world', 'version': (2, 7, 16, 'final', 0)}
python3.7 {'hello': 'world', 'random': 87425, 'random_twice': 174850, 'version': (3, 7, 6, 'final', 0)}
```